# Pthread executes unexpectedly in C

Tags: c, multithreading, file-io, pthreads

I am trying to write a program which gets input files and prints included items into the screen by threads. However, last thread doesn't give any output unexpectedly. I couldn't figure out what the problem is. I am waiting for your help.

Each thread gets 3 parameters :inputFile1, inputFile2 and targetBuf(lets say it is sequence number.) Files are sorted, I just simply try to print their union in order. Only positive numbers are printed.

Command line : merge N outfile file1 file2 file3 .... fileN 
N is the number of input files.

If I give 2 input files (means 1 thread), it works. If I give 4 files, then 1st thread give output, 2nd one does not. If I give 6 input files, then 1st and 2nd threads give output but 3rd doesn't.

There are two structs in header file. I pasted them below.

```
//thread information
struct threadInfo{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
};
//Beginning thread input
struct beginThreadInput{
    FILE **inputFile1, **inputFile2;
    int targetBuf;
};
typedef struct threadInfo THREADINFO;
typedef struct beginThreadInput BEGINT_INPUT;
```

Main File Code:

```
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <unistd.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #include <pthread.h>
      #include <semaphore.h>
      #include <sys/types.h>
      #include <errno.h>
      #include <sys/mman.h>
      #include <sys/stat.h>
      #include <unistd.h>
      #include <fcntl.h>    //for O_ constants
      #include <sys/stat.h>
      #include <pthread.h> /* thread library */

      #include "merge.h"



      int main(int argc, char** argv){
        int i, k, N;

        /***FILE INITIALIZATION***/
        FILE *output;
        N = atoi(argv[1]);
        output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        FILE **inputFileList = ((FILE**)malloc (N * sizeof(FILE*)));
        printf("int N is %d\n", N);
        for(i = 0; i<N; i++){
            inputFileList[i] = fopen(argv[i + 3], "r");
        }
        //START THREADS
        BEGINT_INPUT **threadInputList = ((BEGINT_INPUT**) malloc ( (N/2)*        sizeof(BEGINT_INPUT*)));
        THREADINFO **threadInfoList = ((THREADINFO**) malloc ( (N/2) *          sizeof(THREADINFO*)));
        for(i = 0; i< N/2 ; i++){
            threadInputList[i] = (BEGINT_INPUT *) malloc (sizeof(BEGINT_INPUT));
            threadInfoList[i] = (THREADINFO *) malloc (sizeof(THREADINFO));
        }
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        for(i = 0, k = 0; i < (N/2); i++){


            threadInputList[i]->inputFile1 = &(inputFileList[k]);
            threadInputList[i]->inputFile2 = &(inputFileList[++k]);
            threadInputList[i]->targetBuf = i;
            pthread_attr_init(&(threadInfoList[i]->attr));
            pthread_create(&(threadInfoList[i]->tid), &(threadInfoList[i]->attr), runBeginningThreads, (void*)threadInputList[i]);

        }
        pthread_join((threadInfoList[[(N/2)-1]]->tid), NULL);
        for(i = 0; i<N; i++){
            fclose(inputFileList[i]);
        }

      }

      void *runBeginningThreads(void *input){

        BEGINT_INPUT *myInput = (BEGINT_INPUT *)input;
        int first = -1, second = -1, iseof;
        printf("Thread number %d\n", myInput->targetBuf);
        while((second > -2) && (first > -2)){
            //read integer values from files
            if(first == -1){
                iseof = fscanf(*(myInput->inputFile1), "%d", &first);
                if(iseof == EOF){
                    first = -2;     //means end of file
                }
                else if(first < 0)
                    first = -1;     //means waiting for an integer
            }
            if(second == -1){
                iseof = fscanf(*(myInput->inputFile2), "%d", &second);
                if(iseof == EOF){
                    second = -2;
                }
                else if(second < 0)
                    second = -1;
            }
            //print smaller one
            if((first != -1) && (second != -1)){
                if(((first < second) || (second == -2)) && (first != -2)){
                    printf("%d\n", first);
                    first = -1;
                }
                else if(second != -2){
                    printf("%d\n", second);
                    second = -1;
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question in the following way. As it is seen above, I open the files in main function, then pass them into corresponding threads. I have changed this way and passed the names of the files into threads and open related files in them.

Additionally, while passing files, I was making mistakes, its code is below

```
 threadInputList[i]->inputFile1 = &(inputFileList[k]);
 threadInputList[i]->inputFile2 = &(inputFileList[++k]);
```

This lines are run in a loop. This causes an input sequence like the following ([0,1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4] ...) becuase I increment k only one time.However, each thread takes two of inputFiles. So the correct code is this:

```
 threadInputList[i]->inputFile1 = &(inputFileList[k++]);
 threadInputList[i]->inputFile2 = &(inputFileList[k++]);
```

I want to point out an issue. I fixed this code for file names, not FILE pointer variables as it is posted there. But to make it clear, I fixed the bug on a code posted there. Thanks for your help, everybody

Answer (score 2):

The main problem might be that you only wait for one thread to finish, before you close all files and then exit from the program.

There are a few other extra complications in your program, that could probably be simplified. I mean that you use extra pointer indirection when you don't really need it.

Here's a little simpler version, not using extra pointer-to-pointers where none are needed:

```
struct beginThreadInput{
    FILE *inputFile1, *inputFile2;
    int targetBuf;
};

/* ... */

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    /* ... */

    BEGINT_INPUT *threadInputList = malloc ( (N/2)*        sizeof(BEGINT_INPUT));
    THREADINFO *threadInfoList = malloc ( (N/2) *          sizeof(THREADINFO));

    pthread_t tid;
    for(i = 0, k = 0; i < (N/2); i++){
        threadInputList[i].inputFile1 = inputFileList[k];
        threadInputList[i].inputFile2 = inputFileList[++k];
        threadInputList[i].targetBuf = i;
        pthread_create(&(threadInfoList[i].tid), NULL, runBeginningThreads, &(threadInputList[i]));

    }
    for(i = 0; i< N/2 ; i++){
    pthread_join((threadInfoList[i]->tid), NULL);
}

    /* ... */

    /* While not strictly needed, you should make it a good
       habit of freeing all you allocate */
    free(threadInfoList);
    free(threadInputList);

    return 0;  /* You missed this */
}
```

Comment: You are right. But it is not as you said, becuase I wait for last thread, and last thread doesn't give any output. If I wait all threads, this situation isn't changing, I have already tried.If we say we have N threads, first N-1 of them work correctly. The problematic one is last one.

Comment: @Shnkc You can not wait for what you think is the "last" thread, as the order they run in might not be the order they are created in. Remember that threads are run independently of each other.

Comment: Ok Joachim Pileborg. I got the point. I am editing the posted code above immediately as you said. But same problem still exits. I hope I could fix it in a right way.